# Nested dictionary from Django QuerySet

Tags: python, django

I am stuck in creating nested dictionary from Django QuerySet
My code is

```
qr_dict = [{'id':i.pop('ID'), 'data':[{i['ACCOUNT_NAME']}] } for i in query_result]
```

i got the result from code listed above:

```
[{'id': 123, 'data': [{'MUHAMMAD ADNAN'}]}, {'id': 123, 'data': [{'NAVEED AHMED SUNNY'}]}]
```

i need the result like following dictionary list:

```
[{'id': 123, 'data': [{'MUHAMMAD ADNAN'},{'NAVEED AHMED SUNNY'}]}]
```

what is wrong i am doing please help thanks in advance.

Comment: can you post the content of query_result ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `dict.setdefault`

**Ex:**

```
result = {}
for i in query_result:
    result.setdefault(i['ID'], []).append(i['ACCOUNT_NAME'])
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use collections.defaultdict:

```
from collections import defaultdict

result = defaultdict(list)
for d in query_result:
    result[d['ID']].append(d['ACCOUNT_NAME'])

qr_dict = [{'id': k, 'data': [{e} for e in v]} for k, v in result.items()]
```